# What is the principle behind this struct syntax? How can I make Visual Studio accept it as being correct?

Tags: c, visual-studio

The code below is a snippet from an an open source C program. Visual Studio points out the dots in the lower struct member as errors. What is the principle behind the weird syntax and how can I make Visual Studio accept it as being correct. I know it is correct. I have seen it time and time again in open source code but each time VS reject it, I dump the code. I feel I should take the bull by the horn, this time around.

```
static struct scrypt_test{
      const char *passwd;
      cosnt char *salt;
      uint64_t N;
      unint32_t r;
      unint32_t p;
      uint8_t result[TESTLEN];
 } testcase = {
      .passwd = "pleaseletmein",
      .salt = "sodiumChloride",
      .N = 16,
      .r = 8,
      .p = 1,
      .result = { /*some entries*/}
 }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It is the [designated initialization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) of the struct variable `testcase`. It should be supported since C99.

Comment: Microsoft's support for "modern" C has traditionally been very limited.

Comment: [Struct and union initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization)

Comment: What version of Visual studio are you using?

Comment: Use a standard compliant compiler. The code is correct (presuming the missing definitions are correct).

Answer (score 1):

Designated initialiers are not supported by Visual Studio. Use simple braced initializer.

EDIT: MSVS15 supports designated initializers. Actually MSVS13 and MSVS14 also support them, but they have some [known bugs](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805981) regarding designated initializers.

Comment: Even with c99/11 switch (not sure it exists, though..)

Comment: Wow! They finall managed to support some of the simpler features of a 17 year old version of the C standard? So we can expect C11 support in - 2028? ;-}

Answer (score 1):

> What is the principle behind the wied syntax

The brace-enclosed code following `testcase =` is an initializer for variable `testcase`.  It uses C99-style designated initializers to clarify which struct element is initialized by each member initializer inside.  The format is `.<member_name> = <member_value>`.  In addition to clarity, this form allows you to give members in any order, as well as to skip members, though the code presented does not exercise those options.

> how can I make visual studio accept it as being correct.

You cannot make older versions of VS accept this code.  Not accepting it is one of several ways in which those versions of VS do not conform to C99, much less to C2011.  If you're stuck using old VS to build C projects, then you need to be prepared to alter the code to something that it will accept.  In this case, that would mean removing the member designators:

```
// ...
} testcase = {
    "pleaseletmein",
    "sodiumChloride",
    16,
    8,
    1,
    { /*some entries*/}
};
```

Without designators, the member initializers must appear in the same order as the members themselves do in the struct declaration.

But if you can upgrade to the latest VS, or if you can dump VS for something better, then those would probably be your best options.

Comment: Is there finally full C99 support? If not, better advice would be to use a compliant compiler like gcc or - afaik - clang.